# Re-aligning dataset so that different period appear on the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have each entity data over three different [periods]. These are: 2022-03-31, 2021-09-30 and 2021-03-31

I want to alter the dataset and have

```
2022-03-31  AS [curr_period], 2021-09-30 AS [prev_period] and 2021-03-31 AS [prev2_period].
```

This can as such easily done by case statements.

The problem is, I want that data to be aligned, so that [entity] appears and then on the same line [curr_period], [prev_period], [prev2_period]

How can this be achieved?

Row (over) ? But I don't think it would actually be doing what I want.
What other method is there?

Comment: Show some sample data and the expected result. Please also include your attempt

Comment: provide the table structure so that solution can be provided accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say alter database, do you mean to create a new table for this entity or are you just looking to have a select query?
Do you know those dates for certain or do you also need to sort them by date and get first, second and third?

If you know these dates for certain and they don't change then why do you use them as hard-coded like this

```
SELECT entity, '2022-03-31'  AS [curr_period], '2021-09-30' AS [prev_period], '2021-03-31' AS [prev2_period]
FROM entities
Group by entity
```

I might be missing something but it's hard to know for sure without example data.

This works for me without hard-coded dates.

```
SELECT e1.entity, 
e1.date AS [curr_period], 
e2.date AS [prev_period], 
e3.date AS [prev2_period]
FROM entities e1
join entities e2 on e2.entity = e1.entity and e1.date > e2.date
join entities e3 on e3.entity = e1.entity and e2.date > e3.date
order by e1.entity, e1.date desc
```

Comment: Belongs in the comments

Comment: A select statement is enough and there is no sorting needed, thank you

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks John I know, unfortunately, I am yet to earn the right to comment. Weirdly I am allowed to answer questions before commenting.

Comment: @Anna I have edited my answer, see if that works for you.

Comment: @upzis EXCELLENT !!! had to worked around the dates a bit, but that you, the double re join is the solution !

Comment: @Anna Nice, glad I could help. If you don't mind can post your final code? We are all learning here.